# Aerox 155 max rpm dropped to 7000 rpm

Tags: rpm, scooter, aftermarket-upgrade, pulley

Good day everyone, need help with my aerox 155 issue after installing an after market pulley and driveface. Including iridium spark plug. My aerox 155 cannot go beyond 7000 rpm at full throttle. As a result my top speed was reduced.. can anyone help me with this? Thank you

Comment: Sir what do you suggest?

Comment: That you delete this and don’t post duplicates, for suggestions / answer see your other question.